# Employee_Problems System

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, system-analysis

-> I need to create system for Employee_Problems in Enterprise .
-> Each employee in your work meet many problem that need to repair such as : malfunction in your computer,broken chair,....
-> My analysis to this system is : 
Employee report your manager about your problem. Your manager see the priority of the task and then start to send problem to manager of another department.
the received manager view the problem and assign task to employee to solve the problem.the problem may solve by this employee and the problem will solve or the problem need another employee to solve it,so the received manager begin to assign (forward) task to another employee. Finally after the problem is solved the received manager sent to sent manager (the problem is solved) and the manager ask the employee about your problem already solved or not and evaluate the service and other manager begin evaluate the employees.[image]

Comment: This looks like a homework dump.  Could you edit to clearly state what the question is?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to build a trouble ticket system with a workflow. You could start here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee342461.aspx